# Room with RxJava3

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I tried to use `Flowable` on Room DAO but it is giving me this error:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
Flowable<List<Category>> getAllCategories();
```

My query looks like this:

```
@Query("select * from categories_table order by name;")
Flowable<List<Category>> getAllCategories();
```

Dependencies:

```
def room_version = "2.3.0-beta01"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version"
```

Answer (score -1):

To fix this, try changing the `implementation` value to `"androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0-beta01"`, and for the `annotationProcessor` use `"androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0-beta01"`.